# Finding max value of a field available in all tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Example scenario:
5 tables are there and one common field among them is com_field (DATE data type). Now, I need to find the maximum of com_field in each of the five tables. Can someone give the logic?

I know UNION could be used but I need the flexibility not to miss any new table added to the OWNER.

The result I am expecting is like the below.

```
Table Max(com_field)
Tbl1  10/21/2019
Tbl2  10/18/2019
Tbl3  10/28/2019
Tbl4  09/30/2019
Tbl5  09/09/2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Run this query:**

```
 SELECT 
  'SELECT '''||OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME ||''' AS TABLE_NAME , '||'MAX(COM_FIELD)AS COM_FIELD FROM '  ||OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME ||' UNION ALL'
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME ='COM_FIELD'
```

then copy the outpu and delete last `union all`  keyword. Then run the sql statement.

You can order it and see the max value

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use dynamic SQL in a function that returns refcursor. Here's an example.

First, test case:

```
SQL> create table taba (com_field date);

Table created.

SQL> create table tabb (com_field date);

Table created.

SQL> create table tabc (com_field date);

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into taba values (sysdate)
  3    into taba values (sysdate - 2)
  4    into taba values (sysdate - 3)
  5    into tabb values (sysdate + 2)
  6    into tabc values (sysdate + 4)
  7    into tabc values (sysdate + 5)
  8  select * From dual;

6 rows created.

SQL>
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_maxcom
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(1000);
  5    rc    sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select table_name
  8                  from user_tab_columns
  9                  where column_name = 'COM_FIELD'
 10                 )
 11    loop
 12      l_str := l_str ||
 13               'select ' || chr(39) || cur_r.table_name || chr(39) || ', ' ||
 14                'max(com_field) from ' || cur_r.table_name || ' union all ';
 15    end loop;
 16
 17    l_str := rtrim(l_str, ' union all');
 18
 19    open rc for l_str;
 20    return rc;
 21  end;
 22  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> select f_maxcom from dual;

F_MAXCOM
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

'TAB MAX(COM_FI
---- ----------
TABA 29.10.2019
TABB 31.10.2019
TABC 03.11.2019


SQL>
```

Add another table to see what happens; function will stay *as is*:

```
SQL> create table littlefoot (id number, com_field date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into littlefoot values (100, sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select f_maxcom from dual;

F_MAXCOM
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

'LITTLEFOO MAX(COM_FI
---------- ----------
LITTLEFOOT 29.10.2019
TABA       29.10.2019
TABB       31.10.2019
TABC       03.11.2019


SQL>
```

Seems to be OK, eh?

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot! It works fantastic. Thank you again!